# Project updated from beta-3 isn't producing outputs on build

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

After upgrading a project from the `.kproj` format to the `.xproj` format, my project is no longer producing outputs on build.

- When I check the project properties dialog, the checkbox for "Produce Outputs on Build" is unchecked. Checking it, saving the properties, and re-opening the project properties causes the checkbox to be unset again.
- When I open the `.xproj` file, I see that it contains the expected settings:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
  <ProduceOutputsOnBuild>True</ProduceOutputsOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, when upgrading projects, some of the imports tend to get placed in the wrong order. In my upgraded `.xproj`, at the bottom, I found these lines:

```xml
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props" />
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.targets" />
```

When I compared this with a fresh .xproj file, they were as follows:

```
<!-- after the first PropertyGroup, but before the "Globals" -->
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
<!-- at the end, as before -->
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
```

Moving the `Microsoft.DNX.Props` reference above the `PropertyGroup` containing `ProduceOutputsOnBuild` fixed the issue.  (Since `$(VSToolsPath)` is set in the first `PropertyGroup`, the condition has no effect.)